# Show count of occurrences when smart highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, highlighting, find-occurrences

Is it possible to show the number of occurrences of words which are smart highlighted? I mean when you double click on a word.

In Matlab e.g. smart highlighting is activated by having the cursor touching a word and in the tool bar it *instantly* says for instance `4 usages of "weight" found`.

Doing a search for the word/phrase will give you the same information, but how about having the count directly be shown somewhere?

BTW: Can smart highlighting be activated in a different manner than double clicking?

Answer (score 50):

You can get counts of words or matches in other ways.

The normal **Find** window has a **Count** button. If you press it, it will display the total number of items found in the status bar of the find window.

Also the **Mark** tab of the **Find** window shows the number of items found when **Mark all** is pressed. In addition, the items found by this kind of search are highlighted permanently.

Comment: No, this is  not what @embert asked for. Find does not **instantly** tell you the number of occurances, only after a few click. I would use this feature to check if some variable declarations are not used any more in my code.

Comment: @HenkWiersema Did you read the first sentence of this answer? Where it says *"... other ways"*? Did you read the second sentence about *"... mark all is pressed"*? That is not a few clicks. What was the point of your comment on an answer that is over 3 years old?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14992/show-count-of-occurrences-of-a-selected-string).

- Download and install the **python script** plugin
- Plugins --> Python script --> New script
- Name it `SelectedTextCountIntoStatusBar.py`
- Paste this, save and quit:

`def callback_sci_UPDATEUI(args):
        if args['updated'] & UPDATE.SELECTION:
            matches = []
            if editor.getTextLength() < 100000:  # don't search "big" files
                if editor.getSelections() == 1 and not editor.getSelectionEmpty():
                    try:
                        editor.research(r'\Q' + editor.getSelText() + r'\E', lambda m: matches.append(1))
                    except:
                        matches = []
            l = len(matches)
            notepad.setStatusBar(STATUSBARSECTION.DOCTYPE, ' ' if l == 0 else '{} occurrence(s) of selected text'.format(l))
    editor.callback(callback_sci_UPDATEUI, [SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.UPDATEUI])`

- Plugins --> Python script --> Scripts --> SelectedTextCountIntoStatusBar
- Double-click on a word
- The number of occurrences is in the status bar.

Comment: wow, this is such a useful plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Notepad++ does not show the count for smart highlighting (i.e. highlighting words by double-clicking on one occurrence).

> ... but how about having the count directly be shown somewhere?

**As an alternative:**

- open the Find window (`Search > Find...`)
- Navigate to the `Mark` tab
- Type the word in the `Find What:` input area
- Click `Mark All`

This will mark all the occurrences as well show the count of matches in the status bar.

> BTW: Can smart highlighting be activated in a different manner than
>   double clicking?

There is another alternative for smart highlighting using `Style Token` which is available from the right-click context menu. Watch the animated tutorial below:

[image]